# Jmeter - Regular Expression Extractor to ignore new line

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and I am trying to use Regular Expression Extractor to extract a single value from XML response of one of the HTTP requests. I am aware of the expression I need to use to extract the value but I don't have an idea of how to escape or ignore or include the new line. Below is the small part of my XML response and regular expression extractor that I am using to extract the value between "name" child/sub node:

```
 <com.mfs.model.connector.ConnectorBrowseInfo>
          <type>css</type>
          <name>Cascading Style Server</name>
          <typeGroup>css</typeGroup>
```

**Regular Expression Extractor configuration:**

```
Name of created variable: connectorNameVar
Regular Expression Extractor: <com\.msf\.model\.connector\.ConnectorBrowseInfo>\n          <type>(.*?)<\/type>\n          <name>(.*?)<\/name>\n
Template: $2$
Match No.: 0
Default Value: NotFound
```

This expression return "NotFound" value instead of taking the value 'Cascading Style Server" Can anyone please help me figure out what I need to add or remove or change in my expression?

Acceptance Criteria: The name needs to be extracted from `'<com.mfs.model.connector.ConnectorBrowseInfo>'` this node.

Comment: Your regex worked for me just by replacing **<com\.boomi** with **<com\.mfs** in your Regular Expression Extractor

Comment: In same XML response, I have following node, subnode and child node: 


          <com.msf.model.platform.common.Container>

            <containerId>abhc-123abh-Fgh%908-5rmka</containerId>

            <hostName>EQ AMC</hostName>
            <name>kkp_test</name>
When I use same regex as mentioned above it won't take any value

Comment: Well, your regex is written to extract the name value from this node `<com.mfs.model.connector.ConnectorBrowseInfo>` which is the node you specified in your question not this one `<com.msf.model.platform.common.Container>`.

Comment: Right, that was my initial question - I am using the same regex in my apache-jmeter-4.0 and it is taking Default Value "NotFound" so this regex is not working correctly to extract " Cascading Style Server" and reuse it in upcoming request/s.

Thank you for your response

Comment: You can try this regex, it is working fine for me
https://regex101.com/r/jEsTjq/1

Comment: This Regex works in the available online tools to test the regex expression, but when I use it in Jmeter, it will return "NotFound" value.

Comment: It does work on jmeter as well :) https://ibb.co/61S0c00

Comment: Can you tell me, what is the "Template" no. and match no. you are using in the Regular Expression Extractor? I am using "$1$" for Template no. and "0" for Match no. with your provided regex. and it is still giving me NotFound value.

Comment: May be a stupid comment, but is this on Windows? Then you should test '\r\n' instead of '\n' ! (regex101.com use only '\n', which is why it would work there.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions for parsing XML is not the best idea, JMeter comes with [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) queries in order to get the data from XML/XHTML/HTML responses.

So instead of trying to create an ugly fragile multiline regular expression which will break if the order of attributes change or if the response will come as a single line you could come up with a simple readable and maintainable XPath query, in your case it would be something like:

```
//com.mfs.model.connector.ConnectorBrowseInfo/name/text()
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/)